# Background image won't stretch to footer

Tags: html, css

So I am building my website. I added my banner , my footer but my background is getting messed up. It's not stretching out , there is some empty whitespace.

[This is what happens:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJfcQ.png)

If I use background-size: 100% , my background disappears. Same thing when I use background-size: cover;.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
min-height: 690px;   
background: url("background.png")
background-size: 100%;
}

.footer {
min-height: 200px;
background: url("footer.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: Try `background-size:  cover;`

Comment: background disapears from elements when I do this

Comment: Are you certain your content div actually fills the entire space? (also you are missing a `;` after your `background: url('background.png')` line. This will cause the rest of the css to not be applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.content {
min-height: 690px;   
background: url("background.png");
background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.footer {
min-height: 200px;
background: url("footer.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

You have missed `;` after `background: url("background.png")`.

Try this code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of background-size: 100%, try background-size: cover. Cover will stretch the image to always fully fill its container, cropping any excess.

Comment: When I do this , the background just dissapears.